# Mysterious int value from default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

When I run the program I get garbage values instead of 2 and 4 and 6.

```
-858993460
-858993460
Sum of potion charges: -858993460Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can't see why the constructor would initialise anything but the parameters i gave in main.

potions.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "potions.h"


int Potion::getCharges() const
{
    return potion_charges;
}

Potion::Potion()
{
    int potion_charges = 0;
}

Potion::Potion(int charges)
{
    int potion_charges = charges;
}

Potion::~Potion()
{
    ;
}

Potion operator+(const Potion &potion_charges1, const Potion &potion_charges2)
{
    return Potion(potion_charges1.potion_charges + potion_charges2.potion_charges);
}
```

potions.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef POTIONS_H
#define POTIONS_H

class Potion
{
private:
    int potion_charges;                                                                 
public:
    Potion();                       // Default constr
    Potion(int charges);            // Overloaded constr
    ~Potion();                      // Destr
    int getCharges() const;
    friend Potion operator+(const Potion &potion_charges1, const Potion &potion_charges2);
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "potions.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Potion potion1(2);
    Potion potion2(4);
    Potion potion3 = potion1 + potion2;
    cout << potion1.getCharges() << endl
        << potion2.getCharges() << endl;
    cout << "Sum of potion charges: " << potion3.getCharges();
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never update the member variable `potion_charges`, and so it contains garbage values because it is uninitialized.

Comment: Post text, not pictures of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the constructors

```
Potion::Potion()
{
    int potion_charges = 0;
}   
Potion::Potion(int charges)
{
    int potion_charges = charges;
}
```

You're defining and initializing local variables named `potion_charges` which have nothing to do with the member variable `potion_charges`; the member `potion_charges` is not initialized at all.

Change them to:

```
Potion::Potion()
{
    potion_charges = 0;
}
Potion::Potion(int charges)
{
    potion_charges = charges;
}
```

Or use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Potion::Potion() : potion_charges(0) {}
Potion::Potion(int charges) : potion_charges(charges) {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

Like **songyuanyao** says. You never update your member variable, only a local variable with the same name.

I suggest you clean up your class definition, and build it with a modern compiler:

```
class Potion
{
private:
    int potion_charges = 0; // Follows the c++ core guidelines. The default value
                            // is in the class definition itself.                                                            
public:
    Potion(int charges) : potion_charges(charges)
    {}
    int getCharges() const;
    friend Potion operator+(const Potion &potion_charges1, const Potion &potion_charges2);
};
```

Your class also doesn't need a user defined destructor, since it manages no resource. It's usually best to follow the [Rule of Zero/Three/Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Unfortunately VS2015 didn't provide me with a warning, but thanks to both of you that's one mistake I'll never make again :)

Comment: @PaulPawłowski - Variable shadowing is legal C++. So it's usually hard to get compilers to warn about it. Glad you got your help on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
Potion::Potion() : potion_charges(0) {}
Potion::Potion(int charges) : potion_charges(charges) {}
```

Your potion_charges in constructor is auto variable, not the filed of your class.